# django update field of nested model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Alert which has a foreignkey to user (One user can have multiple alerts defined)

Then I have a model called Notice which has a foreignkey to Alert (One alert can have multiple notices)

In some part of my business logic, I need to update a field of All notices that belong to a specific User from which I have the id (I mean, all notices that belong to alerts that belong to this user)

I need to this using the orm like this

```
Notice.objects.filter(alert__user=1).update(sent=True)
```

can this be done? without nesting for loops?

Comment: yes that worked @levi I thought that worked only for User.objects.filter(alers__notices__sent=true) for example (the inverse way) but it works for both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had a problem in my dataset, my question is answering itself,

```
Notice.objects.filter(alert__user=1).update(sent=True)
```

Works perfectly well